Flask in PythonAnywhere. Returning unexpected HTML page
Iam trying to use flask to build a web app hosted by pythonanywhere. When iam a sub html page (accessed by pressing a button) I get transported to a page where I can make a POST request using the download button. That POST request should return main.py and therefore execute the function. However it executes the index.html file in a different folder (the homepage file) can anyone help me as to why this is happening? Many thanks in advance!
This is my current file structure:

mysite/flask_app
mysite/templates/index.html
mysite/static/style.css

mysite/private_repos/templates/login.html
mysite/private_repos/templates/private_repos.html
mysite/private_repos/static/script.js
mysite/private_repos/static/style.css

mysite/youtube_downloader/templates/index.html
mysite/youtube_downloader/static/style.css
mysite/youtube_downloader/main.py


My flask_app.py looks like this:
`from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from youtube_downloader.main import app as youtube_downloader_app
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Mount the YouTube Downloader application at the '/download/' path
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/download/': youtube_downloader_app
})

# Blueprint setup in flask_app.py
private_repos_bp = Blueprint('private_repos', __name__,
                             template_folder='private_repos/templates',
                             static_folder='private_repos/static',
                             url_prefix='/private_repos')

@private_repos_bp.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@private_repos_bp.route('/private_repos')
def private_repos():
    return render_template('private_repos.html')

app.register_blueprint(private_repos_bp)`


MY WSGI looks like this:

`import sys
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Adjust the paths below to point to your project directories
path_to_youtube_downloader = '/home/wajvdvlugt/mysite/youtube_downloader'
path_to_flask_app = '/home/wajvdvlugt/mysite/'

# Add your project directories to sys.path
if path_to_flask_app not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path_to_flask_app)

if path_to_youtube_downloader not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path_to_youtube_downloader)

# Import the Flask applications
from flask_app import app as flask_app  # Adjust the import as per your main app
from youtube_downloader.main import app as youtube_downloader_app  # Import 'app' from your youtube_downloader/main.py

# WSGI application variable
application = flask_app  # Set one of your Flask apps as the default

# Mount the other application on a subpath
application.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(application.wsgi_app, {
    '/download': youtube_downloader_app
})`
`

My Main.py looks like this:
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_from_directory, url_for, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
from pytube import YouTube, exceptions
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='youtube_downloader.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

DOWNLOADS_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'downloads')
os.makedirs(DOWNLOADS_DIR, exist_ok=True)

@app.route('/download/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    logger.debug("Accessing the '/' endpoint")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logger.debug("Handling POST request")
        logger.debug('POST data: %s', request.get_data(as_text=True))
        data = request.get_json()
        logger.debug('JSON data: %s', data)

        urls = data.get('urls', [])
        download_links = []
        error_messages = []

        for url in urls:
            try:
                yt = YouTube(url)
                video_stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
                if video_stream:
                    video_filename = secure_filename(yt.title) + '.mp4'
                    video_stream.download(output_path=DOWNLOADS_DIR, filename=video_filename)
                    download_links.append(url_for('download_video', filename=video_filename, _external=True))
                    logger.debug(f"Downloaded video: {video_filename}")
            except exceptions.PytubeError as e:
                error_message = f'Error for URL {url}: {str(e)}'
                error_messages.append(error_message)
                logger.error(error_message)

        response_data = {'download_links': download_links}
        if error_messages:
            response_data['errors'] = error_messages
        logger.debug('Response data: %s', response_data)
        return jsonify(response_data)

    logger.debug("Rendering template for GET request")
    return render_template('youtube_downloader.html')

@app.route('/download/<filename>')
def download_video(filename):
    logger.debug(f"Downloading file: {filename}")
    return send_from_directory(DOWNLOADS_DIR, filename, as_attachment=True)

CORS(app)

The index.html file (the homepage in a different folder) looks like this:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Projects Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Welcome to WenA</h1>
            <h2>Explore our repository of free projects. Registered user? Login to access our private projects.</h2>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
<button onclick="location.href='/youtube_downloader/download/'">
    <span>YouTube Video Downloader</span>
</button>

</li>
<li>
<button onclick="location.href='{{ url_for('private_repos.login') }}'">
    <span>Private Repo Login</span>
</button>
</li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
<footer>
    Created by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/wessel-van-der-vlugt-351213254/" target="_blank">Wessel van der Vlugt</a>
</footer>
</body>
</html>`


My youtube_downloader.html file (which the button on index.html should route you to) looks like this:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> <!-- Using container to center everything and apply flex styling -->
        <header>
            <h1>YouTube Video Downloader</h1>
        </header>

        <!-- Form for entering YouTube URL -->
            <form action="/download/" method="post" id="download-form" class="project-card">
            <label for="video-url">Enter YouTube Video URL:</label><br>
            <div id="url-container" class="input-container">
                <input type="text" name="url[]" id="video-url" required>
            </div>

            <br>
            <button type="button" id="add-more">Download More</button>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Download" class="download-btn">
        </form>

        <!-- Messages and spinner for feedback -->
        <div id="message"></div>
        <div id="spinner" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
        <footer>
            Created by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/wessel-van-der-vlugt-351213254/" target="_blank">Wessel van der Vlugt</a>
        </footer>
    </div>

   <script>
document.getElementById('download-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting normally

    // Clear any previous messages
    document.getElementById('message').textContent = '';

    // Gather all the input URLs
    let urls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="url[]"]')).map(input => input.value);

    // Send the URLs to the server
    fetch('/download/', {  // Corrected path
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ urls: urls })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.download_links && data.download_links.length > 0) {
            let messageContent = '';
            // Create clickable links for each download
            data.download_links.forEach((link, index) => {
                messageContent += `<p><a href="${link}" target="_blank" download>Download Video ${index + 1}</a></p>`;
            });
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = messageContent;
        } else if (data.errors && data.errors.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('message').textContent = 'Some errors occurred:\n' + data.errors.join('\n');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('message').textContent = 'No videos to download.';
        }

        // Reset the input fields to only one with empty value
        const container = document.getElementById('url-container');
        container.innerHTML = ''; // Clear all existing inputs
        addInputField(); // Add a single empty input field
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Show error message
        document.getElementById('message').textContent = 'An error occurred. Please try again.';
    });
});

function addInputField() {
    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.type = 'text';
    newInput.name = 'url[]';
    newInput.required = true;
    newInput.style.width = '100%';
    newInput.style.padding = '10px';
    newInput.style.margin = '5px 0';
    newInput.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
    document.getElementById('url-container').appendChild(newInput);
}

document.getElementById('add-more').addEventListener('click', function() {
    addInputField(); // Use the new function to add input fields
});
</script>

</body>
</html>`

This is my networking log:
Request log
Response log
I tried rewriting the flask_app.py to have an unique route when compared to index.html (as seen above) but it didn't seem to work. (Or I did it incorrectly)
Help is appreciated, iam lost at what is causing it/how to fix it. Thanks!
